# "Agua hirviendo" | ¿Cuál es la función del gerundio?

Tags: gramática, gerundio

En esta clásica línea,

1. *Póngalo en agua **hirviendo**.*
2. *Póngalo en agua **que esté hirviendo**.*

¿Cuál es la función del gerundio en este caso? ¿Son equivalentes las afirmaciones?

Comment: Parece un adjetivo de "agua", ¿no?

Comment: Funciona como adjetivo como en (_rolling stones_) Piedras rodando ;-)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo en tal caso (de ser adjetivo), sería *hirviente*

Comment: @guifa ¿pero el gerundio no hace hoy día las veces del perdido participio presente?

Comment: @DGaleano pero en ese ejemplo *rodantes* sería el adjetivo. 

Comment: Hice una edición a la pregunta para que la vean.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo no, excepto con tres verbos, de los cuales está incluido *hervir*.  Nadie (espero) hablaría de una durmiendo mujer.  Lo que sí se puede usar es el gerundio como complemento predicativo, que a veces puede parecer ser de uso adjetival.

Comment: @guifa es muy común usar *mujer durmiendo* donde se podría usar *mujer dormida*

Comment: @rshanchez ¿podrías decir "mira esa mujer muy durmiendo" en dicho contexto? Si no, todavía estaríamos hablando de un complemento predicativo. (No pretendo corregirte, obviamente no conozco todos los disturbios y siempre es posible que haya desarrollos que no haya aparecido todavía en los libros)

Comment: Quise decir «dialectos» no «disturbios»,.... autocorrect >:(

Comment: @aparente001 *agua hirviendo* viene de antes de la influencia del inglés en la lengua española.

Comment: "Mujer durmiendo" se oye como el título de un cuadro. // @guifa - Me gustó más "disturbios."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Según la *Nueva Gramática*, es algo peculiar que acaeció al verbo.  Su gerundio se ha lexicalizado y se ha quedado en la lengua como un adjetivo propio (además de su función como forma verbal):

> **27.2a** Se usa el gerundio como adjetivo en las formas lexicalizadas *ardiendo* e *hirviendo*, y, con mayores restricciones, también *colgando*.  Estos gerundios pueden funcionar sintácticamente de manera similiar a los modificadores restrictivos o especificativos (*El agua hirviendo es la de la cazuela grande*), lo que en general está vedado a otros gerundios. […]

Prueba de ello podría ser lo siguiente (tomo algunos ejemplos de 27.2b de la *NGE*).

1. La vi *llorando* <sub>(= ella está llorando)</sub>
   es complemento predicativo porque
2. La vi *llorando **mucho*** <sub>(= ella está llorando mucho)</sub>
   está bien dicho, pero intensificándolo como adjetivo
3. La vi ****muy** llorando*
   no lo está.

Fíjate la diferencia con *hervir*:

4. Póngalo en agua *hirviendo* <sub>(= el agua está hirviendo)</sub>
   se puede modificar como si fuese adjetivo
5. Póngalo en agua ***muy*** hirviendo <sub>(= el agua está hirviendo mucho)</sub>
   y no con *mucho*
6. Póngalo en agua *hirviendo ***mucho***

Otra prueba de que la forma *hirviendo* no se puede ver como simplemente una estructura de tipo adjetivo verbal generalizada es que no podemos sustituir otros verbos allí.  No podemos decir **el agua congelando* ni **el agua virtiendo* en este mismo contexto (no obstante, la forma *-nte* sí funciona: *agua congelante* <sub>(que congela)</sub>, *agua [virtiente](https://books.google.ch/books?id=mAEXAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA221&lpg=PA221&dq=%22agua%20virtiente%22&source=bl&ots=MpsRxxtmPH&sig=YOD4Nbf_TmQHTHFInnv8A3tdMeg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22agua%20virtiente%22&f=false)* <sub>(que vierte)</sub>).

Resumiendo lo dicho: efectivamente ***hirviendo* en este contexto es adjetivo** invariable en número y género que significa *hirviente / que hierve*, **en vez de un gerundio propiamente dicho**.

---

<sup>(Dícholo todo, voy a seguir usando *hirviente* jaja.)</sup>

Comment: La que me has armado para que al final des la razón a mi primer comentario a la pregunta. :-D (+1 por la explicación, me ha quedado claro).

Comment: @carlosalejo bueno, no es mi culpa que una forma errónea haya pasado al lenguaje culto, esa culpa la tenéis los nativos ;-)

Comment: ¡Agua muy hirviendo! Suena terrible...

Comment: Y ¿"agua para chocolate"?  ¿Hierve?