# ¿Es «hirviendo» un adjetivo masculino?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, género, participio

¿Por qué «agua hirviendo» parece ser de género masculino mientras que «agua carbonatada» parece ser de género femenino?

¿Es «agua hirviendo» un error? Lo veo a menudo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "agua" masculine in singular form and feminine in plural? "El agua" / "Las aguas"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la)

Comment: en ambos casos debe ser "el agua" sin embargo agua es del genero femenino

Comment: ¿y cuál seria el femenino de hirviendo? El hecho de que termina en "o" no lo hace masculino y no es un adjetivo. El adjetivo seria "Agua **hervida**" en femenino.

Comment: Ver [“Agua hirviendo” | ¿Cuál es la función del gerundio?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20562/agua-hirviendo-cu%c3%a1l-es-la-funci%c3%b3n-del-gerundio)

Comment: tal vez la respuesta a esta pregunta pudiese incluir una explicacion sencilla respecto a las inflecciones aparentemente ambiguas para el genero de el vital protoxido; podria ser que la pregunta se reptia porque la original requiere de algun ejemplo o discusion mas sencilla en estos finos puntos del lenguaje y @hcbowman nos da la oportunidad de hacerlo.

Comment: @Mike, no creo que sea un duplicado, pese a que ambas se refieren al género de la palabra agua. En este caso el problema se refiere exclusivamente al singular, y no incluye el artículo. La duda parece venir más bien del uso del gerundio, que al terminar en -o suena masculino al oído no-nativo

Comment: Ya casi nos hace falta el tag "agua". No entiendo bien cómo lo hacen, pero tal vez sea bueno canonizar esta pregunta (¿se dice así, canonizar?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Menudo adjetivo has elegido para hacer esta pregunta.

Tenemos dos hechos curiosos que seguramente te han causado la duda:

1. La palabra *agua* es femenina, pero empieza con /a/ tónica, por tanto, emplea el artículo feminino *el*.
2. El adjetivo *hirviendo* es invariable en cuanto a género (y número).

Para el primero, nota la evolución que habría tenido la palabra agua, fonéticamente:

```
Almost Latin   Early Romance    Modern
-----------------------------------------
 illa aqua        ellagua       el agua
illas aquas    ellas aguas     las aguas
  una aqua         unagua       un agua
 unas aquas     unas aguas    unas aguas
```

As you can see, because of the way the *ella* sounds right in front of *agua*, it ended up evolving into *el* instead of *la*.  But it's pure coincidence that it looks like the masculine *el* that came from *ille*.  Although the exact phonetic rules varied a bit over time, if the article came directly in front of certain words that begin with an /a/, you could get this special version of *la*.  But the word was still feminine (remember, that *el* is technically feminine too!), so all adjectives would agree (*el agua fría y clara*).  And if the adjective got placed between the article and the noun, it would revert to the standard *la* (*la cristalina agua*).

En el caso de *hirviendo*, tenemos un ejemplo de un error que tras el tiempo ha ido ganando terreno a la forma técnicamente correcta.  *Debe* ser *hirviente* que es adjetivo de pura cepa.  No obstante, el gerundio, *hirviendo* ya se usa como adjetivo. Siendo la terminación *-iendo* una no marcada para género (es decir, no indica por sí el género, aunque termine en *-o*), ni tampoco se marca por número, aunque los gerundios *nominales* suelen adquirir marcas por número (*los doctorandos*).  Hay *muy* pocos gerundios que han surgido como adjetivos.  De hecho, solo son tres: *ardiendo*, *hirviendo* y *colgando*.

Entonces, considerando lo de arriba, ¿qué sabemos?  *Agua* es voz femenina siempre, aunque tenga un artículo que hace que parezca masculina.  *Hirviendo* es adjetivo invariable, y no importa que el sustantivo sea masculino o femenino, o singular o plural, siempre tendrá la misma forma.

Al final, acabamos con que *el agua hirviendo* sea una locución femenina: *agua* es femenina por naturaleza, *el*<sub>(de *illa*)</sub> también lo es, e *hirviendo* se trata como femenina aunque no demuestre su feminidad de forma evidente.  Si la pusiésemos en plural, tendríamos *las aguas hirviendo*, con lo cual creo que lo antedicho salga más obvio.

Comment: Ojo que _hirviendo_ no es un adjetivo ;)

Comment: @Rafael Así lo recoge la Nueva Gramática (pero curiosamente no el DLE).

Comment:  ¡No puedo creerlo! Es un cambio en las reglas del juego comparable a [aceptar _kilo_ con q](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UrLQxnC). Encontraba mucho más sentido a la explicación del gerundio aceptado excepcionalmente sin verbo principal

Comment: @guifa uno de los párrafos está en inglés y el resto de la respuesta al igual que la pregunta, en español.

Comment: @guifa - ¿El *codeswitch* fue a propósito?

Comment: @aparente001 no, no sé por qué me cambié de idioma jaja, voy a traducirlo

Comment: @guifa - Me pareció *codeswitching* puro y sencillo, debido a los encabezados (Almost Latin,   Early Romance,    Modern) que copiaste de alguna fuente.  Luego con *cristalina agua* ya entraste en el otro mundo.

Answer (score 3):

**Agua** es del género femenino, eso hace que cualquier adjetivo que posea deberá ser del género femenino.

“**Hirviendo**” no es un adjetivo, es un verbo en presente continuo y carece de género.

Comment: It looks as though you voted to close, and also wrote an answer.  Once in a while one feels a need to do this -- but I would recommend including, maybe in parentheses, a short explanation.  In this particular case, because the boiling water part of the question doesn't seem to have been asked yet here, I would recommend retracting your close vote and adding to your answer something like "Also see (link)."  If you ever want to retract a close vote, here's how: hit "close" again, and you'll be given an opportunity to retract....

Comment: Nice answer by the way.  And if you want to strengthen it -- how about offering a better way of talking about boiling water?

Answer (score 2):

Ideas clave:

- [**Agua**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1BKpQj3) es **femenino** por definición y los adjetivos que la acompañan deben concordar en género (deben ser [femeninos](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=agua)).
- Como indica guifa, cuando lleva artículo, usa [***el***](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=agua) en lugar de *la*, como muchos otros sustantivos femeninos comenzados en *a*, por razones histórico-fonéticas.
- Como varios notaron, **hirviendo**, es una forma verbal impersonal (concretamente, un [gerundio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J9jq94P%7CJ9k4n78)), y por lo tanto no varía con el género.

  - Aunque en castellano el gerundio ordinariamente es un adverbio y debiera modificar a otro verbo ("verbo principal"), en este caso estamos frente a un gerundio especificativo, que según [este sitio](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Gerundio#Gerundio_del_nombre_o_gerundio_especificativo), sería un galicismo y constituye una excepción aceptada por la RAE.
- Finalmente, es relativamente [común encontrar errores](https://www.google.cl/search?q=%22el%20agua%20hervido%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=pwfWWseeBsf8wgT6zL_oDA) o concesiones a la regla de que *agua* es de género femenino, pues el uso del artículo *el* sin duda se presta para confusión. Por ejemplo, más abajo pongo una cita de un [blog](http://idejaime.com/patagonia-argentina-i-peninsula-valdes/) escrito por un madrileño en que habla de **el frío agua*. Creo recordar que una concesión de este tipo era comúnmente aceptada en Argentina a fines del s. XX, pero no logro dar con una fuente.

En consecuencia, y en respuesta a tu pregunta: **agua hirviendo** **NO es un error**. ***Hirviendo* no es necesariamente masculino**, y **el sustantivo *agua* es siempre femenino** aunque vaya acompañado del artículo *el* (e incluso de vez en cuando leas a hablantes nativos acompáñandolo de adjetivos masculinos).

---

Extracto del blog mencionado más arriba. Como se desprende del DPD, lo correcto sería *el agua fría*, *la fría agua* o *las frías aguas* (en un contexto de marina):

[image]